# Empty Array inside Controller's function called from Directive - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-material

I'm having a pretty tricky problem that seems to be trivial but I'm not finding a good way to solve it.

Essentially, I'm building a todo list application using **Angular** and **Angular-Material**.

I have a **main.html** where, the important part is:

```
<md-content ng-show="mainCtrl.todos.length">
   <md-list class="todo_list" flex>
     <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">{{mainCtrl.todoList.label}}</md-subheader>
       <acme-todo ng-show="mainCtrl.todos" ng-repeat="todo in mainCtrl.todos track by $index"
                  text="todo.content" index="$index"></acme-todo>
   </md-list>
</md-content>
```

Where `acme-todo` is a directive which contains a **todo.html**:

```
<md-list-item layout='row' layout-sm='column' layout-align='center center' layout-wrap>
    <i class='material-icons md-avatar'>border_color</i>
    <div class='md-list-item-text'><h3>{{mainCtrl.text}}</h3></div>
    <div class='md-secondary'>
        <md-button class='md-fab md-primary md-small box red-btn'
                   aria-label='delete' ng-click='mainCtrl.deleteTodo(mainCtrl.index)'>
            <i class='material-icons small-icon'>highlight_off</i>
        </md-button>
    </div>
</md-list-item>
```

Where **todo.directive.js**:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('todoApp')
        .directive('acmeTodo', acmeTodo);

    function acmeTodo() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                text :  '=',
                index : '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'todo.html',
            controller : 'MainController',
            controllerAs : 'mainCtrl',
            bindToController : true
        };

        return directive;
    }

})();
```

And finally, **main.controller.js**:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('todoApp')
        .controller('MainController', MainController);

    function MainController() {

        var vm = this;
        vm.todos = [];

        . . .

        vm.addToDo = addToDo;
        vm.deleteTodo = deleteTodo;

        //vm.todo.content is the ng-model of the input-box
        function addToDo() {
            if( vm.todo && !_.isUndefined(vm.todo.content)){
                   pushNewToDo(vm.todo.content);
            }
        }

        function deleteTodo(index) {
            vm.todos.splice(index, 1);
        }

        function pushNewToDo(todo) {
            vm.todos.push({ content : todo });
            vm.todo.content = '';
        }

    }

})();
```

> Everything works fine except when deleting a todo. When `deleteTodo`
>   is called, the function correctly receives external `$index` from
>   main's `ng-repeat` but, can't find out why, `vm.todos` is empty at
>   that moment, so, nothing gets deleted.

If, instead, I manage to move all of **todo.html** content at `acme-todo` place's everything works fine.

I also tried setting `$scope : true` in the directive instead of passing both `text` and `$index` but I'm still encountering the same problem.

Here is a working [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMKQNJ) which reproduces my issue. N.B. On the CodePen I'm using `template` instead of `templateUrl` and I changed the icons just to make things work properly there.

Here's a screen of the real application:

[image]

I know that, by default, if I do not specify any controller, the directive will still pick its scope, but

**EDIT**

Using a `Service` or a `Factory` also solves the problem like in [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWxaGW) solves the problem, but I feel like adding way too much logic for such a small thing.

**Why Am I getting an empty todos array even thought both controller and directive share the same scope? How can I fix that keeping the same approach (using a todo directive)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate app and directive controller because when you're initializing directive you're creating new controller, so new `$scope` and new `todos` array locally inside directive. After that you can pass delete function from the main controller to directive's `$scope`.

Take a look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZWyLV